# How is operator.eq implemented in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, operators

When we print `operator.eq.__name__` we get the output `'eq'`. This implies that operator.eq is a class. 
But we can use it as a function as well. `operator.eq("test", "test")` returns `True`.
How is operator.eq implemented? Is it a class or a function?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but FWIW I do explain how a `.eq` comparison works under the hood in python.

Answer (score -1):

`operator.eq` is a function of the `operator` module. All functions have a `__name__` attribute, as do most classes.

`eq` is pretty simple, take a look at the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/operator.py#L35):

```py
def eq(a, b):
    "Same as a == b."
    return a == b
```

You can demonstrate this in CLI with the following code.

```py
def cool_name():
    pass

class NeatName:
    pass

print(cool_name.__name__)
print(NeatName.__name__)
```

Interestingly, a function is still a class, and can be treated like one. You can assign properties and functions to another function.

```py
cool_name.foo = "foo"
print(cool_name.foo)

def bar_func():
    print("bar")

cool_name.bar = bar_func

cool_name.bar()
```

Comment: "All functions have a `__name__` attribute, as does nearly every object in Python" - on the contrary, most objects do not have a `__name__`. It's mostly just functions and classes that have a `__name__`.

Comment: "Interestingly, a function is still a class, just like everything in Python" - this is also wrong. Functions are not classes. Most things in Python are not classes.

Comment: Since the base `object` implements `__name__`, wouldn't that, by default, mean most Python objects have `__name__`? The only ones I can think of that don't are the built-in types.

Comment: No. Contrary to common misconception, objects do not automatically have all attributes of their class. Default attribute lookup behavior includes a search through the `__dict__`s of an object's class and all superclasses, but that search won't find class attributes that are resolved through the *metaclass*.

Comment: Sorry I am new to python. I am coming to python from c++ and the concept of function having attributes is new to me. How can function have attributes? Can you redirect me to any useful link where I can find more details?